# ORA-06550 PLS-00103 error:encountered the symbol

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-06550, pls-00103

```
create or replace PROCEDURE empl_info(ename VARCHAR2,empid OUT 
NUMBER,empcount OUT NUMBER,empname OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(emp_name) INTO empcount FROM employees WHERE emp_name=ename;
SELECT emp_name, emp_id INTO empname,empid FROM employees WHERE 
emp_name=ename;
END;


DECLARE en INT,ei INTEGER,ec INT;
EXECUTE empl_info('balu',ei OUTPUT,ec OUTPUT,en OUT);
 SELECT en,ec;
```

error:
ORA-06550:line 1,column 15
PLS-00103:encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following.

can you solve this?

Comment: completely edited from the beginning in my below answer, according to run on sql developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the proper syntax of `ANONYMOUS BLOCK`

```
DECLARE 
    en NUMBER;
    ei NUMBER;
    ec NUMBER;
BEGIN
    empl_info('balu',ei,ec,en);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EN :'||en);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EC :'||ec);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SQL> CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE empl_info(ename VARCHAR2,empid OUT NUMBER,empcount OUT NUMBER,empname OUT VARCHAR2) IS
> BEGIN
>   SELECT COUNT(emp_name) INTO empcount FROM employees WHERE emp_name=ename;
>   SELECT emp_name, emp_id INTO empname,empid FROM employees WHERE emp_name=ename;
>   dbms_output.put_line(' employee name : '||empname||'  |  employee count : '||empcount);
> END;
> ```

*just call variables without OUT or OUTPUT*

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> var ei number;
SQL> var ec number;
SQL> var en varchar2(100);
SQL> exec empl_info('balu',:ei,:ec,:en);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds inadequate but I could get rid of this error when I called the procedure and the parameters on the same line.

So, when I called the procedure like below I got "*ORA-06550:line 1,column 32 PLS-00103:encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following.*" error:

```
EXEC PR_UNITE_FILES( 

PARAMETER1,

PARAMETER2

);
```

But, when I called the procedure like below, I got no errors:

```
EXEC PR_UNITE_FILES(  PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2 );
```